# Unable to bundle resource file in executable as images in gtkmm using c++

Tags: c++, gtkmm

Unable to bundle .png in my executable created using GTKmm in C++

I am working on GTKmm using C++. My project requirement is to add certain images(say icons/.png) in the executable. Executable is working fine in my build path where as it doesn't works anywhere else(due to file not found).

What should be the approach to bundle the images to executable (to make a distributable executable)

I have tried almost all the approaches available online.

// Sample code

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Gtk::Main kit(argc, argv);
    Gtk::Window win;
    Gtk::Table tb_png;
    Gtk::VBox mainBox;
    Gtk::Alignment* alignment;

    win.set_position(Gtk::WIN_POS_CENTER);
    win.set_title("PNG");
   //window.set_default_size(800, 900);
    win.set_size_request(620,565);
    win.set_resizable(FALSE);
    win.set_icon_from_file("imagem/newlogobmp.bmp");

    Gtk::Image step1("imagem/step01.png");
    alignment = Gtk::manage(new Gtk::Alignment);
    mainBox.pack_start(*alignment,Gtk::PACK_SHRINK);

    Gtk::Alignment mywidget(0.1,0.2, 0.9, 0.8);

    tb_png.attach(step1,0,1,0,1); //
    mywidget.add(tb_png);

    // Put widget in middle alignment
    alignment->add(mywidget);
    win.add(mainBox);

    win.show_all();
    kit.run(win);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please add the necessary code to the question that is just enough to reproduce the problem. Also, are using a `glade file + Gtk::Builder` in your project? Your question is a bit terse without adding those specifics.

Comment: Thanks for replying, i am not using Glade file +Gtk::Builder in my project.i have updated my code snippets.

Comment: Is the `imagem` directory in the same folder where your source file is located?

Comment: Yes,this is diretory in the same folder.

Comment: If you run the script from an IDE, then it should be in the directory where your source `.cpp`files are located. If you're running the program from the command line or straight from the command line, `imagem`  should be in the same directory as the executable.

Comment: From [this](https://developer.gnome.org/pygtk/unstable/class-gtkwindow.html#method-gtkwindow--set-icon-from-file), the icon is used when *and only when*  the window is minimized. Also, you could check the return value ie `true == win.set_icon_from_file("imagem/newlogobmp.bmp")`